# Flutter const: need it on sub widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the differences between this two code snippets?

```
const Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, top: 20),
                              child: const Text(
                                "Password",
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: myColor,
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),


const Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, top: 20),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Password",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: myColor,
                                      fontSize: 15.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
```

Is it necessary to specify the const keyword also in the sub widgets like in the first snippet? Or is it enough to do it only in the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference.

Since Dart 2, only the first `const` is necessary, such that:

```dart
const Foo(Bar())
```

is strictly equivalent to:

```dart
const Foo(const Bar())
```